# How to find the match from list of maps with list of keys in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure.

I have a map s1 and a vector s2

```
(def s1 {:params [{:param  :begin_date
                 :name     "begin date"
                 :dtk      :date
                 :param_operand :single}
                {:param  :begin_num
                 :name     "begin num"
                 :dtk      :numeric
                 :param_operand :single}
                {:param  :begin_num2
                 :name     "begin num2"
                 :dtk      :numeric
                 :biparam_operand :single}]})

(def s2 [:begin_date :begin_num])
```

I am trying to find the match from s1 with s2. I.E iterate through each element from s2 and find the match from s1.
If the match exists check the type for :dtk, if the type is :date then we accept that map.

This is the code which I have tried, when I had to find if the match exists using just one element from the list s2 - :begin_date

```
(defn test->map
  [s1 s2]
  (let [test-vec (->> s1
                      :params
                      (filter (fn [typet] (= (:param typet) :begin_date)))
                      first
                      :dtk)]
    (when (= test-vec :date)
      "done")))
```

How to modify the above function in a way that it should be able to iterate over the entire list of elements and find a match.
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it using [`keep`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep):

```
(defn match [k]
  (->> s1
       :params
       (keep
        (fn [{:keys [param] :as v}]
          (when (= param k)
            v)))
       first))
```

or by using [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) with `:when`:

```clj
(defn lookup [k]
  (first
   (for [{:keys [param] :as v} (:params s1)
         :when (= param k)]
     v)))
```

(This is bit similar to your approach with `for` and `filter`. Only `:when` does the filtering now, and I return the actual value  instead of the string `"done"`.)

With result:

```clj
(map lookup s2)
;; => ({:param :begin_date, :name "begin date", :dtk :date, :param_operand :single}
;;     {:param :begin_num, :name "begin num", :dtk :numeric, :param_operand :single})
```

I would personally transform the current data structure `s1` to a Clojure map (for example via [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce)) once, so you can access the params by key and use [`select-keys`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys). Then you don't have to iterate over the whole of s2 for every lookup.

```clj
(defn transform [s1]
  (reduce
   (fn [acc {:keys [param] :as v}]
     (assoc acc param v))
   {}
   (:params s1)))

(transform s1)
;; => {:begin_date
;;     {:param :begin_date, :name "begin date", :dtk :date, :param_operand :single},
;;     :begin_num
;;     {:param :begin_num, :name "begin num", :dtk :numeric, :param_operand :single},
;;     :begin_num2
;;     {:param :begin_num2,
;;      :name "begin num2",
;;      :dtk :numeric,
;;      :biparam_operand :single}}

(select-keys (transform s1) s2)
;; => {:begin_date
;;     {:param :begin_date, :name "begin date", :dtk :date, :param_operand :single},
;;     :begin_num
;;     {:param :begin_num, :name "begin num", :dtk :numeric, :param_operand :single}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Erwin. This solution helps.

But what if I also want to filter the resultant maps to find :dtk type and accept :dtk :date.

Comment: @Sourab E.g., prefiltering: `(filter (comp #{:date} :dtk) (:params s1))`. Filtering afterwards you might miss entries when using an approach with `first`.

Comment: Also my function should accept two parameters s1 & s2. Tried with passing two params and filter. No luck. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Sourab to pass two parameters you have to change the signature, e.g.,`(defn lookup [s1 k] ...)`, and pass along extra parameters to functions that need it. For example, to pass `s1` to the new `lookup` you could use [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial): `(filter (partial lookup s1) s2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Modified the function as below. 

`(defn lookup [s1 k]
  (filter (comp #{:date} :dtk) (:params s1))
  (first
   (for [{:keys [param] :as v} (:params s1)
         :when (= param s2)]
     v)))`

`(filter (partial lookup s1) s2)` 


Resulted in (:begin_date :begin_num)

Comment: The below code works fine 

`(defn lookup [s1 s2]
  (first
   (for [{:keys [param] :as v} (filter (comp #{:date} :dtk) (:params s1))
         :when (= param s2)]
     v)))`
Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.